# Global Address book

Tags: exchange-2003

I created a new user and distro list from exchange 2003 and I found out that my newly created email account and distro list is not updating or showing up when somebody look from the address book. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Access your `Exchange System Manager`, expand `Recepients`, `Offline Address` book and in the right pane click `update`.
On the client -> `send/receive`, `download offline address book`.

Comment: i only see there is rebuild?

Comment: That's fine. Will work too.

Comment: By default, the OAB re-creation is 5AM each day. You can adjust it if you have a lot of "user change" activity.

Answer (score 1):

How long have you waited?

The offline address list does not immediately update with new users.  It updates on a defined schedule, or an update can be forced from within Exchange System Manager.

Comment: it's been a week and it still doesn't show up the other thing that I noticed, when I'm creating a new mailbox or DL, there are no x400 configuration on the email address tab, by default it should be automatically created as it was on the policy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the new user account and new distribution list to verify that they were not accidentally created with the option selected to "hide from global address list"?

Another important thing to check is whether or not the client machines that are running Outlook have their Exchange account running in cached mode.  If they do, it can take a very long time for the change to process (sometimes as long as a day or two in our environment).

Any easy way to check if this is the problem is to disable cached mode for the exchange account in Outlook, restart Outlook, and see if the new user/distr list is now there.